# Security Issue on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

on sample android application to access database Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html), we just need to write

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");
```

The problem is, if someone know my firebase url "https://.firebaseio.com/", they will be able to manipulate my data from their application.
How to secure connect to Firebase? like a facebook or Google Api give us APP-Key or Secret.
-Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Step 7 in the [quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html) you linked:

### Secure Your Data

> Use our powerful expression-based [Security and Firebase Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html) to control access to your data and validate input:

```
{
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth.uid === 'admin'",
  ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 500"
}
```

> Firebase enforces your Security and Firebase Rules consistently whenever data is accessed. The rules language is designed to be both powerful and flexible, so that you can maintain fine-grained control over your application's data.

Comment: but if want to give access to all users of my application than? I just want to protect my data from other application.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase security is not based on API keys/secret but in permission rules. Check [this](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) out.

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to make everything only writable you add the following security rule:

{
     "rules": {
         ".read": false,
         ".write": true
     }
   }

And it is also worth noting that these rules will cascade to all child nodes and you cannot override them in child nodes except for validation rules.