# How to protect database from other application in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am working on an Android application which uses Firebase database as a backend. Now I am afraid that if anyone can get my Firebase URL, they can manipulate my data. I also studied answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587266/security-issue-on-firebase).

One of its answer is saying like this `".write": "auth.uid === 'admin'",`

But I want to give database access to all of my users only through my application. So how can I do this? Please advise. There is an option available in the Manage Project section to add `Fingerprint` but has not helped me.

Comment: As long as the database rules for write and read are "auth != null" only authenticated users from your app can read or write to the database. See here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: There is no way to protect the database to only allow access by your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005984/how-to-prevent-other-access-to-my-firebase Instead: Firebase's security model is based on authenticating each user and then ensuring they only have access to data they're authorized for. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949097/swift-firebase-how-to-ensure-no-one-can-access-my-db-except-my-app